# Is there a way to remove image metadata from all existing images in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a huge S3 bucket of images, it's impractical to manually edit each one or write a script to strip the metadata one by one, is there another way to strip the image metadata from all of the images?

To be clear: I mean the image metadata (Exif etc), NOT the s3 metadata.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, I recommend using S3 Batch Operations + AWS Lambda scripts to do this.